# Google image download with python cannot download images

Tags: python, google-image-search

I'm using `google_images_download` library to download top 20 images for a keyword. It's worked perfectly when I'm using it last days. Code is as follows.

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download

response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()

arguments = {"keywords":keyword,"limit":10,"print_urls":True}
paths = response.download(arguments)
```

Now it gives following error.

```
Evaluating...
Starting Download...


Unfortunately all 10 could not be downloaded because some images were not downloadable. 0 is all we got for this search filter!

Errors: 0
```

How can I solve this error.

Answer (score 27):

There has been some changes on Google end (how they respond to the request) which results in this issue. **Joeclinton1** on github has done some modifications to the original repo which provides a temporary fix.

You can find the updated repo here: https://github.com/Joeclinton1/google-images-download.git . The solution is in `patch-1` branch if I'm not mistaken.

1. First uninstall the current version of google_images_download.
2. Then manually install Joeclinton1's repo by:

```
git clone https://github.com/Joeclinton1/google-images-download.git
cd google-images-download && sudo python setup.py install #no need for 'sudo' on windows Anaconda environment
```

or to install it with pip

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Joeclinton1/google-images-download.git
```

This should solve the problem. Note that currently this repo only supports upto 100 images.

Comment: If you have already installed google-images-download, you can use pip to uninstall the package.

Comment: Ya @HiranyaJayakody, I later found that I didn't used pip to install the earlier repo, just used setup.py. I don't know how to undo that step, but pip installing Joeclinton1's repo on top just runs without any problem. Thanks.

Comment: Lifesaver! I used to use google_images_download and it stopped working. Pexels downloads garbage. This works!

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same issue with google-image-download, which used to work perfect earlier!
I have an alternative that I would like to suggest, which should solve the problem.

Solution: Instead of using google-image-download for Python, use bing-image-downloader, that downloads from Bing! search engine.

**Steps:**

**Step 1:**
Install the library by using: `pip install bing-image-downloader`

**Step 2:**

```
from bing_image_downloader import downloader
downloader.download(query_string, limit=100,  output_dir='dataset', 
adult_filter_off=True, force_replace=False, timeout=60)
```

That's it! All you would need to do is to add your image topic to the query_string.

**Note:**

Parameters that you can further tweak:

query_string : String to be searched.

limit : (optional, default is 100) Number of images to download.

output_dir : (optional, default is 'dataset') Name of output dir.

adult_filter_off : (optional, default is True) Enable of disable adult filteration.

force_replace : (optional, default is False) Delete folder if present and start a fresh download.

timeout : (optional, default is 60) timeout for connection in seconds.

*Further Reference: https://pypi.org/project/bing-image-downloader/*

Comment: Yes, it's cool, but keep in mind that this does not solve the problem: bing-image-downloader often misses 100% of its results, or nearly 100%.  It fails most of the time, and there's no indication as to why.

Comment: Thanks @SubhrajeitBhowmick for the answer! I was trying to download more than 100 images with google-images-download, but since Google changed the images format, I can't download them anymore. bing-image-downloader works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to download less than 100 images per query string, `google-images-download` will work better than `bing-images-downloader`. It handles the errors better and, you know, Google Images gives quite better results than Bing equivalent.

However, if you're trying to download more than 100 images, `google-images-downloader` will give you a lot of headaches. As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60556289/13695889), Google changed their end, and because of this the repo is having a lot of failures (more info on the situation status [here](https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download/issues/348)).

So, if you want to download thousands of images, use `bing-image-downloader`:

Install package from pip

```
pip install bing-image-downloader
```

Run query.

**NOTE:** The documentation seems to be incorrect, as it returns a "No module found" error when importing the package as `from bing_image_downloader import downloader` (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64460085/13695889)). Import it and use it like this:

```
from bing_image_downloader.downloader import download

query_string = 'muscle cars'

download(query_string, limit=1000,  output_dir='dataset', adult_filter_off=True, force_replace=False, timeout=60, verbose=True)
```

Comment: This answer still holds true to 2022-6-23, `bing_image_downloader` works right out of the box, though if you really want to use google images, you should perhaps try their own API.

Answer (score 3):

Another easy way to download any number of images :-

pip install simple_image_download

from simple_image_download import simple_image_download as simp

response = simp.simple_image_download
response().download(a, b)

Where a= string of subject you want to download
B= number of images you want to download

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax